# upload chunks using dropbox api

Tags: python, file-upload, dropbox

I am using the dropbox API to upload files in chunk. But the following code gets stuck at uploader.upload_chunked(). What might be the reason?

Also, is there any way to know what is happening in the background like uploaded these many chunks, still uploading, time taken to receive the uploaded chunks and other information ?
Can threads be used to upload these chunks,assuming that the API takes measure to assemble the chunks in correct order,or is it that we have to take care of ordered assembling ?

```
import dropbox
size = 941   
access_token = 'xxx'
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)
to_upload_file = open('dummy.txt','r')

uploader = client.get_chunked_uploader(to_upload_file,size)

print 'uploading ', size
while uploader.offset < size :
        try:
                upload = uploader.upload_chunked(chunk_size=100)  
                print '100 bytes of chunk sent.'
        except dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse,e:
                print 'something went wrong'      
uploader.finish('/dummy.txt')
```

**Edit**:
`size = 941` -> The size of the file to upload
`upload=uploader.upload_chunked(chunk_size=100)` ->  chunk_size changed from default to 100 bytes
`print'100 bytes of chunk sent'` -> print statement included

Comment: When you say it gets "stuck," what do you mean? Do you mean the app hangs? Or you get some error? Or what? Also, where does `size` come from? This snippet doesn't include its definition, so presumably its `None`, which seems invalid.

Comment: stuck as in the code does not proceed beyond the mentioned point in the code. size is arbitrary number of bytes. I mentioned 1024 bytes.

Comment: Is the file actually that big? `size` should be the size of the file you're uploading. If it's not actually 1024 bytes, you might be in an infinite loop. (`uploader.offset` may always be less than `size`) I'm not clear on whether the behavior you're seeing is an infinite loop. (If you added a print statement under `uploader.upload_chunked()`, would it be executed? How many times?)

Comment: I did add a print statement, but it never got executed !

Comment: And is the file at least 1024 bytes long?

Comment: Ok.. the file was not 1024 bytes ! size should be equal to number of bytes to upload ! But, still after adding print statement in the loop and making the chunksize as 100 bytes, the statment prints only once i.e. after the uploading is done ! Any suggestions why ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "chunksize." Do you mean you're passing a `chunk_size` parameter? I.e. calling `uploader.upload_chunked(100)`? Maybe you can update your post with the actual code you're running.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, so I asked in dropbox's [developer forum](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=112984&replies=5#post-598379)
They suggest [upload_chunk](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.upload_chunk) (member function of DropboxClient, not the one in ChunkedUploader) could suit our requirement

Answer (score 2):

`upload_chunked` uploads the entire file (one chunk at a time), so unless an error occurs, the above code should only reach the `print` statement once, after the file has been uploaded.

See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs/python#ChunkedUploader.upload_chunked for the documentation of `upload_chunked`.